# Deleting files automatically using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory /backup that contains other directories with daily backups in them. Those directories are sorted by name and date (BACKUP_date). The few lines of bash script which i had been using before worked until the beginning of a new month and stopped due to some unforeseen situations. this was what i used previously

```
#!/bin/bash

ndate=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
ndays=8
ddate=$((ndate-ndays))

cd /backup || exit
rm -rf BACKUP_$ddate
```

How can i modify this to be much more intelligent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you echo the values, it is obvious what goes wrong:

```
a=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
echo $a
20210906
b=$(($a-8))
echo $b
20210898
```

There is no 98th day in August.

So, a beter way would be to let `date` do the calculation:

```
b=$(date "+%Y%m%d" --date='8 days ago')
echo $b
20210829
```

Comment: This worked on my Linux environment. But when I tried using this on the other Solaris environment, i get 20210906 when i echo $b. I guess there is a difference in how Solaris OS handles date

Comment: Yes, your question was marked "Linux" so I assumed `date` on linux. On Solaris, `date` is more spartan. The easiest solution on Solaris would be to use `gdate`, if that is installed'

Comment: So i had to install a gnu version of the date and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't treat times or Y-M-D dates as plain integers; they have gaps in the value range and ordinary integer operations don't account for them. For example, if your script runs on September 6th, it calculates "ddate" as August *98th*, because `2021_09_06 - 8 = 2021_08_98`.

There are three ways to make this work:

#### Date formats which *are* integers

The `%s` format will give you the date+time as a "Unix timestamp" in seconds since Jan 1, 1970. This *is* an integer and you can simply add or subtract seconds from it:

```
ntime=$(date +%s)
ndays=8
dtime=$(( ntime - ndays*86400 ))
```

Once you have the timestamp for "8 days ago", you can ask `date` to format it using `-d @12345`:

```
ddate=$(date -d "@$dtime" +%Y-%m-%d)
```

#### Let `date` do the calculation

If you want to get a date 8 days ago, you can get it directly using `-d "8 days ago"`:

```
ndays=8
ddate=$(date -d "${ndays} days ago" +%Y-%m-%d)
```

(This can be stacked but in a slightly non-obvious way, e.g. "4 days ago 12 hours ago" instead of just "4 days 12 hours ago".)